# Send email using php mail function. Mail is successfully delivered if i remove image from email

Tags: php, html-email

When i include image in email it shows sending successful but email is not delivered. If i remove image it works successfully and deliver emails.
Here is the function from which i am sending email.

```
$to = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "Invitation";
$from = "Sender Name";
$from_mail = "info@example.com";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ".$from." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$message = " <div style='font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light,Arial,sans-serif;background-color:#eeeeee'>
<table align='center' width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#eeeeee'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='630px' align='center'>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <div style='border:3px solid #0074B6'>
                <a href='http://www.example.com'>
                  <img src='http://example.com/images/store_logo.png' width='600' height='110' style='padding: 15px 0 0 10px;' alt='Invitation' />                    </a>
                <hr style='border:2px solid #0074B6;'>
                <div style='padding: 5px 20px 0; text-align: justify;'>
                  <p>
                    Other text.....
                  </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>";
$sendmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: If you mean you remove the `img` tag HTML from the content, then I don't think that will stop it from sending (what does `$sendmail` contain? true or false). There is a change that it's being picked up as spam though I suppose.

Comment: $sendmail contains result true. You are correct. I also think only img can not stop email. but where I am doing mistake i don't know.

Comment: Then as far as PHP is concerned, the e-mail has sent (or rather been passed over to an MTA). Check your mail logs for further info.

Comment: If the only difference is in the HTML content, then the chances are it's hitting a spam filter. However, one way or the other, I would recommend upgrading from PHP's `mail()` function to something more fit for purpose, such as phpMailer or SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 2):

i am also facing the same problem , you can try one small solution. put your message in single quotes and image tag like this `<img src="http://example.com/images/store_logo.png" width='600' height='110' class="CToWUd">` 
if it stil not work then you can use [PHPMailer][1]

[1]: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer its very easy to use

Answer (score 0):

use the PHPMailer script. You sound like you're rejecting it because you want the easier option. Trust me, PHPMailer is the easier option by a very large margin compared to trying to do it yourself with PHP's built-in mail() function. PHP's mail() function really isn't very good.

To use PHPMailer:

- Download the PHPMailer script from here: http://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
- Extract the archive and copy the script's folder to a convenient place in your project.
- Include the main script file -- `require_once('path/to/file/class.phpmailer.php');`

Now, sending emails with attachments goes from being insanely difficult to incredibly easy:

```
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'you@example.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Your Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Message Subject';
$email->Body      = $bodytext;
$email->AddAddress( 'destinationaddress@example.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'PATH_OF_YOUR_FILE_HERE';

$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'NameOfFile.pdf' );

return $email->Send();
```

It's just that one line $email->AddAttachment(); -- you couldn't ask for any easier.

If you do it with PHP's mail() function, you'll be writing stacks of code, and you'll probably have lots of really difficult to find bugs.